# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR en Heroku al conectar con API

Tags: nodejs, rest, heroku, deployment

La web corre bien pero en cuanto toco alguna funcionalidad que hace una petición (GET o POST) 
Me salta este error en la consola:

> Error: Network Error at e.exports (createError.js:17)
>
> XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:80)

Y este:

> xhr.js:166 OPTIONS https://localhost:4000/api/task
>
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

He mirado en SO y al parecer es porque me falta instalar los certificados SSL para que la web sirva https. Sin embargo en la url se muestra https correctamente **y chrome muestra el icono de que la conexión es segura.** ¿Dónde es el error entonces?

Un ejemplo de una petición en mi frontend:

```
axios.post('https://localhost:4000/api/task' ...
```

Sin embargo en el backend:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, ...
```

Podría ser porque heroku esta sirviendolo en un puerto que no es el 4000 y entonces la ulr en la petición no funciona? Si es así como puedo hacer en el frontend que las rutas a la API van al puerto correcto?

Comment: Hasta donde se tienes que cargar un archivo `.key` y un `.crt` con un import de `https`. Despues  usas `https.createServer({key: fs.readFileSync(...tu key...), cert: fs.readdFileSync(...tu crt...)}, app).listen(..//cb..)`. Eso ya lo hiciste?

Comment: Aun así, si ese código funciona bien en tu pc con chrome es solo por que chrome siempre confia en `https://localhost/`. Intenta conectarte con la ip de tu maquina y veras que te da error...

Comment: @Angel Antes tenía http sólo pero lo cambié a https ya que heroku me servia la web en https. En mi maquina local siempre me daba error pero estuve desarrollando usando la seguridad desactivada en Chrome :S

Comment: @Angel voy a hacerlo y te comento, muchas gracias.